# getting wrong result while merging pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes like-

```
    identity time       Date    matched_time
0   197_$   21:21:21    9/11/2015   21:21:30
0   197_$   21:21:51    9/11/2015   21:22:00
0   197_$   21:22:21    9/11/2015   21:22:30
0   197_$   21:22:51    9/11/2015   21:23:00
0   197_$   21:23:21    9/11/2015   21:23:30
0   197_$   21:23:51    9/11/2015   21:24:00



 identity Line  Epoch   Day Seconds   Date        Time  
    197_$    9344   11203   4   280290  9/11/2015   1/1/1900 21:21  
    197_$    9345   11204   4   280320  9/11/2015   1/1/1900 21:22  
    197_$    9346   11205   4   280350  9/11/2015   1/1/1900 21:22  
    197_$    9347   11206   4   280380  9/11/2015   1/1/1900 21:23  
    197_$    9348   11207   4   280410  9/11/2015   1/1/1900 21:23  
    197_$    9349   11208   4   280440  9/11/2015   1/1/1900 21:24
```

Now I want to merge the columns to create a new dataframe-
I did-

```
df2=pd.merge(df,out,how='outer')
```

but the desired output was not obtained.I just wanted to create a dataframe which has all the columns.

so the dataframe should look like this-

```
identity time       Date    matched_time      Line Epoch  ....
0   197_$  21:21:21    9/11/2015   21:21:30  9344  11203  ....
0   197_$  21:21:51    9/11/2015   21:22:00  9345  11204
0   197_$  21:22:21    9/11/2015   21:22:30  9346  11205
0   197_$  21:22:51    9/11/2015   21:23:00  9347  11206
0   197_$  21:23:21    9/11/2015   21:23:30  9348  11207
0   197_$  21:23:51    9/11/2015   21:24:00  9349  11208
```

Comment: What is the basis for matching between the two DataFrames?

Comment: there are two columns which are common in the dataframe that is identity and Date...I just want to append the two and create a new dataframe which has columns from both the dataframes

Answer (score 1):

In general you should not use `merge()` unless you have unique keys in at least one side (left or right). Instead, use `concat()`
if you have identical columns in both dataframes. I omitted a column `Time` of your 2nd dataframe for simplicity.

`df1`:

```
    identity    time    Date    matched_time
0   197_$   21:21:21    9/11/2015   21:21:30
1   197_$   21:21:51    9/11/2015   21:22:00
2   197_$   21:22:21    9/11/2015   21:22:30
3   197_$   21:22:51    9/11/2015   21:23:00
4   197_$   21:23:21    9/11/2015   21:23:30
5   197_$   21:23:51    9/11/2015   21:24:00
```

`df2`:

```
    identityLine    Epoch   Day Seconds Date
0   197_$   9344    11203   4   280290  9/11/2015
1   197_$   9345    11204   4   280320  9/11/2015
2   197_$   9346    11205   4   280350  9/11/2015
3   197_$   9347    11206   4   280380  9/11/2015
4   197_$   9348    11207   4   280410  9/11/2015
5   197_$   9349    11208   4   280440  9/11/2015
```

Combine 2 dataframes using `concat()`:

```
df3 = (pd.concat([df1.set_index(['identity', 'Date']), 
                  df2.set_index(['identity', 'Date'])], 
                  axis=1).reset_index(drop=False))
```

Output(`df3`):

```
    identity    Date    time    matched_time    Line    Epoch   Day Seconds
0   197_$   9/11/2015   21:21:21    21:21:30    9344    11203   4   280290
1   197_$   9/11/2015   21:21:51    21:22:00    9345    11204   4   280320
2   197_$   9/11/2015   21:22:21    21:22:30    9346    11205   4   280350
3   197_$   9/11/2015   21:22:51    21:23:00    9347    11206   4   280380
4   197_$   9/11/2015   21:23:21    21:23:30    9348    11207   4   280410
5   197_$   9/11/2015   21:23:51    21:24:00    9349    11208   4   280440
```

Hope this helps..